# How do I regex search for python values? """string""", "string", 'string', (tuple), [list], {dict}

Tags: python, regex, parsing, django-settings

I'm trying to extract variables/values from a Django `settings.py` file (preserving comments, whitespace, etc.) and move or append them to another file programmatically using Python.  Overall, I'm trying to split up the settings module into several files automatically (not manually using a text editor).

How do I find the value assigned to any variable in such a file? - If possible in a concise way, e.g. using regular expressions.

**Example variables/values:**

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*'
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'database.sqlite'),
    }
}
SECRET_KEY = '#*ji*0hbpj6#4-0=$%bl(z+z)c=pd(rn^9u*1_96f^ba+4w58v'
LONG_STRING_VALUE = \
"""
bla foo bar baz ...
"""
A_TUPLE = (
    '...',
)
```

**Notes:**

- I read the file as one long string, therefore regex matches can span several lines.
- No need to fully parse/understand the value, just find the closing delimiter.
- I'm wondering if the code of the Python interpreter is available (as a Python module) that parses values in Python code. Anybody knowing?
- Partially working code is on GitHub: [DjangoSettingsManager](https://github.com/bittner/django-organice/blob/develop/organice/management/settings.py#L85) (identifies any variable until after equal sign, as of 15-feb-2014)

  ```
  r'([ ]*#.*\n)*[ ]*(\A|\b)' + var + r'\s*=\s*\\?\s*'
  ```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Test this w/ Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/d6J7NwYldVv-Bo-J)

Comment: @glglgl Of course. Ignore the title, StackOverflow just formats it nicely. It's still 3 straight quote characters.

Comment: Why do you care about transposing comments and retaining formatting? Comments only care for human consumption, and humans can (should!) look at the appropriate source file. For that matter, if you're trying to copy code around as text rather than just importing data items each from their own source file, that's a smell too.

Comment: ...for that matter, copying from the human-edited source files into the final settings.py, rather than having the final settings.py pull _from_ the human-edited source files is also a smell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, it's not a smell, let me explain. The settings module is supposed to be human-consumable (especially) in my project where I'm expecting to expose potentially first-time Django users to the framework. That's one reason why I care about formatting and comments.

Comment: ... And I also care about humans with respect to deployment (that's why I take the ``settings.py`` file and split it up into deployment profiles). And I care about making life easier for upgrading Django (that's why I don't provide templates but I copy/move around parts of the original ``settings.py`` file provided by Django). After all, source code in general is supposed to be human-readable. -- Hence, I'm wondering whether I can't re-use the internal workings of the Python interpreter (source code parser). If that were possible somehow that may be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `django.conf.settings` module, for instance you can know is django is in debug mode or not typing:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.DEBUG
...
```

Doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you say, let Django do the parsing, that's not what I want: I would lose the comments and any white space formatting. (Ack, I left comments out in the example above)